# Mantaflow doesn't look like water after baking

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I'm fairly new to blender, and am trying to follow a tutorial with some fluid simulations.

Every tutorial i see, once the fluid simulation is done and they go to rendered mode, it already looks like water.

Thats not the case for me. It just looks like a normal white mesh.

Have i done something wrong or misunderstood something? Do i need to shader it myself or?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just create a new material and in the *Principled BSDF* move the *Roughness* to 0 and *Transmission* to 1.

You might also want to make sure the *Base Color* is pushed all the way up to white, or you can color your fluid however you want.

They could also be using the default "Liquid Domain Material" created by *Quick Liquid*.

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I really appreciate you taking the time! Thanks alot!